# UTF-8 encoded SQLite queries

Tags: utf-8, sqlite

Right now I have this in my program, to make a query in an SQLite database.

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare(pMinte, "SELECT * FROM 'minte'", -1, &stmt, 0);
```

and it works just fine. But how should I do if I need to query

```
SELECT * FROM 'minte' WHERE something = 'ășîâț'
```

?

Please don't yell at me, I'm a novice.

Comment: As long as your C compiler can understand UTF-8 encoded source files, you would just make your string exactly that. If it can't understand them, you would need to encode the characters yourself for UTF-8 in the string literal and then add them like `"... '\xC4\x83\xC8\x99\xC3\xAE\xC3\xA2\xC8\x9B'"`

Comment: @deceze Well, he's using the C API, so...

Comment: @Jason ...or at least something that *looks* like the C API... The question needs to be tagged with the appropriate language, otherwise the right people won't see it.

Comment: Yes I'm using C++. There is no way I could write them as-is, is there?